# eclipse doesn't show xml errors in preference xml

Tags: android, eclipse, android-xml

I copied several classes from library to the project itself.
In my `values/xml/preferences.xml` I have some custom classes such as CustomListPreference etc...

Problem is that those custom classes were in my library (com.udios.commons) and now they are in my project itself (com.udios.test)
in the preference xml they are still begin with:

```
com.udios.commons.CustomListPreference ..... />
```

and this library doesn't exist anymore. Eclipse doesn't show any error and I've notice to this issue only when the app crashed.

How can I fix it? Thanks for the help.

Comment: What package contain now CustomListPreference class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I fix it?

If the class `CustomListPreference` has chaged from the library to your project, you must change to the new package that contains the class

```
com.udios.commons.CustomListPreference ..... />
```

for example if your class is now inside the folders structure:

```
/com/mypackage/udi/CustomListPreference.java
```

change the references to :

```
com.mypackage.udi.CustomListPreference ..... />
```

Comment: Is there any way to make eclipse to show those errors?